# pharo creating a global variable like transcript

Tags: global-variables, smalltalk, pharo

I want to create a variable named MameGap which is accessible from every where.
I can print some words to transcript for ex. from a method of a class. I want to do this for MameGap too.

I tried something like this

```
MameGap:= MyClass new.
Smalltalk at: #myMap put: MameGap.
```

I want to access MameGap like this

```
doSomething: aVar
   |x|
   x:= MameGap getInt.
   ^x*3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do:

```
Smalltalk at: #MameGap put: MyClass new
```

also you can put there just a class object, like

```
 Smalltalk at: #MameGap put: MyClass
```

and sen to it class-side messages

Comment: This doesn't make 'MameGap' global in the same sense as Smalltalk or Transcript. Typing 'MameGap' in transcript will give An Undefined object.

Comment: Actually this works if you use `Smalltalk globals at: #AKeyStartingWithACapital put: {1. 2. 3.}`. but the key HAS to start with a capital because of poor design decisions.

Comment: my bad, Smalltalk instances define `at:put:` and `at:` to alias to Smalltalk global(slight forwarding overhead but same result).